# MongoDB to Bigquery (batch) dataflow template - UDF not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, user-defined-functions

We are trying load our current data in mongoDB into bigquery on a scheduled basis. And currently trying to use google cloud’s dataflow service working with the MongoDB to Bigquery (batch) template with some UDF. Unfortunately I cant seem to get the UDF to work for this job using the cloud console. The job runs runs perfectly and correctly loads the entire data into bigquery but the UDF function is not applied.
Here is an example UDF I have tried below, this should just add a new string field to the data but that does not work either.

```
/**
 * User-defined function (UDF) to transform elements as part of a Dataflow
 * template job.
 *
 * @param {string} inJson input JSON message (stringified)
 * @return {?string} outJson output JSON message (stringified)
 */
function process(inJson) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(inJson);

  obj.udftest = "udftest";

  return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried to just add an extra field as in the code above but that doesn’t work either, it just loads the flattened data if useroption is FLATTEN and the normal json format if useroption is NONE. The UDF function is totally disregarded and pipeline works successfully without throwing any error.

I have followed this [blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/mongodb-dataflow-templates-udf-enhancement/) from MongoDB using the given function structure and format still to no avail. I have change the obj variable type to a normal **var** instead of **const** but it still did not work. Followed the bigquery documentation and that did not help either.

Comment: Can you check this? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/issues/904#issuecomment-1693360449 and the doc is https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/v2/mongodb-to-googlecloud/docs/MongoDbToBigQuery/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has been resolved. This issue happened because the name of the function in the UDF code was not properly entered in the template creation page.

[image: Screenshot from template]